# Concat&abbreviated name mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have 10 projects and 5 departments. And of course each project is assigned to one of the departments. Now, I want to abbreviate the project name so that the new name is a combination of first four characters of the project name, hyphen, and then the first three characters of the department name. Also the new name should be all uppercase. So let's assume the project name is Computerization in department 4, administration. Then the new abbreviated name must be COMP-ADM
Obviously mysql should automatically do this for all project names. Because if this 10 projects later on increased to 100, I don't want to type 100 statements for each of them. So, is there any easy way to do this without overly complicated statements?

Comment: Take a look at the MySQL [string functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could do something like this whether you are Updating a Column or insert this new name into another table or Column, you can get the required format of Department Name and Project Name but doing this

```
SELECT UCASE(LEFT(ProjectName, 4)) + '-' + UCASE(LEFT(DepartmentName, 3))
FROM Table
```

Comment: I did this way as you suggested:                                                          SELECT UCASE(LEFT(pname, 4)) + '-' + UCASE(LEFT(dname, 3))
FROM 
project INNER JOIN department
ON dnumber=dnum but it throws nothing but bunch of zeros!

Comment: Try `CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(ProjectName, 4)), '-', UCASE(LEFT(DepartmentName, 3)))` instead.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I figured the CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(ProjectName, 4)) part out myself, but I was having problem with the hyphen and the second part. With your help I was able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT UCASE(CONCAT(LEFT(pname, 4))) AS NEW, '-', UCASE(CONCAT(LEFT(dname, 3))) AS NAME
FROM 
project INNER JOIN department
ON dnumber=dnum
```